# How to delete old launch configuration using ansible code

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am working on autoscaling ansible project can somebody tell me how I can delete old launch configuration using ansible playbooks.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, [I've created a pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/1023/files) for a new Ansible module that you could use to find old launch configurations, and delete them.

For example, if you'd like to keep the top 10 most recent launch configurations, and remove old ones, you could have a task like:

```
---

- name: "Find old Launch Configs"
  ec2_lc_find:
    profile: "{{ boto_profile }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    name_regex: "*nameToFind*"
    sort: true
    sort_end: -10
  register: old_launch_config

- name: "Remove old Launch Configs"
  ec2_lc:
    profile: "{{ boto_profile }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: absent
  with_items: old_launch_config.results
  ignore_errors: yes
```